# error in matrix dataset when using boosting function from adabag package in R

Tags: r, boost, adaboost

today I was exploring adaboost technique. however, i copied the following example code from the adabag package document.

```
data(iris)
iris.adaboost <- boosting(Species~., data=iris, boos=TRUE,
mfinal=10)
importanceplot(iris.adaboost)
```

there I didn't get any error after executing the second line.
however when I used the same method for another dataset which was downloaded from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/car+evaluation

```
library(adabag)
library(rpart)

cars <- read.csv("car.data.csv", header= FALSE)

# to view no.of obs in each column
sapply(cars, FUN=function(col) sum(is.na(col)))
# to view rows with missing values
cars[!complete.cases(cars),]

cars.adaboost <- boosting(V7 ~., data=cars, boos=TRUE,
                          mfinal=10)`
```

i get the following errors

```
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
3: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
4: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
5: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
6: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
7: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
8: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
9: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
10: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

I also checked the following for NA in observations

```
 > # to view rows with missing values
> cars[!complete.cases(cars),]
[1] V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

[image: this is the dataset of cars]

can someone help me in getting what I'm missing. i'm sorry if i asked a silly question, as i'm a beginner and started learning machine learning and R since not more than a month?

Comment: Are you sure that the function accepts non numeric variables ?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure. I tried to check regarding this whether the function accepts non-numeric in the internet, but i didn't found anything . then i realized in dataset iris the species variable is non-numeric

Comment: Species are non numeric, but they are at one side of the formula ... other variables are numeric in the iris dataset ..

Comment: yes the other variables are non-numeric too. as you can see in the picture i uploaded.

Comment: So, may be you could try one hot encoding ..

Comment: sorry i don't what it is. can you help me?

Comment: Try `model.matrix` to convert your columns to numeric before you use `boosting`

Comment: i tried using the following line     `model.matrix( ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7, cars)`   but i got the same error when i use the boosting function.